# Service Values Get Empty when Route Changes - Angular 5

Tags: angular, service, angular5

I have a service, dataequipment.service.ts, in which I have a variable "equipmentList".
I set the value of equipmentList from an API, and everything goes fine;
But when I navigate to another component "equipmentList" is empty.

What can I do?

In dataequipment.service.ts I have this

```
equipmentList = [];

addEquipment(element) {
   equipmentList.push(element); 
};
```

Then in the other components I have  equipment.component.ts (for example) and everything works perfectly.
If I access the "this.equipmentList.equipmentList" it shows the elements (working fine)

```
constructor(private _data: DataequipmentService) {}

addEquipment(element) {
this._data.addEquipment(element);
}
```

Then if I navigate to "equipment-details.component.ts" using an link with [routerLink]="equipment-details"

When I try to retrive equipmentList from my service, it is empty.

```
console.log(this._data.equipmentList.lenght); //returns 0
```

Comment: Have you declared this service in app.module/sharedmodule?

Comment: I declared it in de app.module in Providers, providers: [DataequipmentService]

Comment: I found the mistake, it was the "equipment.component.ts" I also had the  providers: [DataequipmentService] inside of @Component. Thanks

Comment: hey @HugoQuiñónez I am having a similar issue. From your comment, did you have to add the `providers` to the component, or remove it? thanks

Comment: ah never mind, you removed it from @Component, thanks